# Sites loading slowly in Windows, possibly due to DNS?

Tags: windows, dns, netbios

I'm using Chrome, on my wife's laptop. Opening chrome takes only a second, as it should. But as soon as I click on any of the thumbnailed sites (reddit.com, as an example), I have to wait. There's nothing in the browser indicating that it's loading, other than `www.reddit.com` appearing in the URL.

I got curious, and started running [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what might be causing the slowdown. That's when I noticed the following entries (*after* I clicked the link):

```
21  7.971612    192.168.1.126   192.168.1.1 DNS Standard query A pazkytgbcc.lan
22  7.972368    192.168.1.126   192.168.1.1 DNS Standard query A krxzlmahld.lan
23  7.973469    192.168.1.126   192.168.1.1 DNS Standard query A idbjtwdafg.lan
24  7.989505    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.126   DNS Standard query response, No such name
25  7.990754    fe80::401e:5f23:4885:605    ff02::1:3   LLMNR   Standard query A pazkytgbcc
26  7.991031    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.126   DNS Standard query response, No such name
27  7.991580    192.168.1.126   224.0.0.252 LLMNR   Standard query A pazkytgbcc
28  7.992852    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.126   DNS Standard query response, No such name
29  7.993054    fe80::401e:5f23:4885:605    ff02::1:3   LLMNR   Standard query A krxzlmahld
```

then later

```
89  12.818203   192.168.1.126   192.168.1.255   NBNS    Name query NB PAZKYTGBCC<00>
90  12.818324   192.168.1.126   192.168.1.255   NBNS    Name query NB KRXZLMAHLD<00>
91  12.818401   192.168.1.126   192.168.1.255   NBNS    Name query NB IDBJTWDAFG<00>
92  13.568167   192.168.1.126   192.168.1.255   NBNS    Name query NB PAZKYTGBCC<00>
93  13.568337   192.168.1.126   192.168.1.255   NBNS    Name query NB KRXZLMAHLD<00>
```

notice that these are repeating "hosts" from the A queries above. Any idea what's causing this? How do I fix it? This makes browsing terribly slow, and my wife is getting frustrated. I've tried adding these entries to the `hosts` file (which, Vista makes incredibly difficult), but to no avail. The hosts seem to be different each time, and I see no standard pattern.

I've run Spybot against her machine, and she has [AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/homepage) installed, and it comes back clean. Other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The computer looks in the local network first. But the DNS servers are not found. After they fail it searches the internet. Look in the hosts file of windows for the servers and delete the hosts or comment the lines. Take a look here to find the hosts file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Comment: Actually, the DNS server is found, but it returns no result, because there is no such domain `pazkytgbcc.lan`. I know about the hosts file. My problem, is how to make it *stop* running these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the random looking domain queries [may be a feature of Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3511015c72a7b314&hl=en). See [this also](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47262&can=1&q=random%20host%20names&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS).

I'm not sure why these queries would hold up web browsing unless Chrome specifically has to await a response. Other than that, the most likely suspect is your DNS.

Try doing `ipconfig /all` at the command prompt to see the what order the DNSs are listed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is your DNS have you tried using a different DNS server?  You should be able to use 4.2.2.2 and 4.2.2.4 or really any other free DNS server to check if that's really the problem.

Comment: I've tried using other DNS servers. Same results.

Comment: @gms8994: Are you just adding the extra servers to the bottom of the list, or are you putting them at the top? Usually when you have the delay, it's because the first DNS is timing out.

Comment: You didn't say you checked other browsers, do they work as expected or are they all slow and produce these messages?

Comment: @Satanicpuppy If there's a way to add them other than through the GUI, I have no idea; but I'm specifically setting the servers to use to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @Jeff I haven't checked other browsers, as Chrome is her primary browser. Once I'm back on the machine, I'll check others as well.

Comment: @gms9884: Do an ipconfig /all, and scroll up to the DNS servers. The one at the top is the first one queried, etc, etc. I see people add new servers for testing, without removing the ones at the bottom.